# El último WHERE me da problemas. ¿Por qué?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

En la siguiente consulta, el último WHERE me da problemas, ¿por qué?

```
SELECT DISTINCT $pregModalidad.numeroPregunta,
$pregModalidad.idPreguntaTest,
$pregModalidad.preguntaTest,
$pregModalidad.respuestaLetra,
$pregModalidad.aRespuesta,
$pregModalidad.bRespuesta,
$pregModalidad.cRespuesta,
$pregModalidad.dRespuesta,
$pregModalidad.eRespuesta 
FROM $pregModalidad 
INNER JOIN respuestasTestUsuario 
ON $pregModalidad.numeroPregunta=respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta 
from respuestasTestUsuario 
WHERE respuestasTestUsuario.respuestasCorrectas=3 AND respuestasTestUsuario.idUsuario=$idUsuario) 
WHERE $pregModalidad.numeroPregunta=$contaPregunta
```

El esquema de la consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM ...
INNER JOIN ... ON ... = ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND ... )
WHERE ...
```

(el problema no tiene nada que ver con los $ que son de las variables php)

Comment: No es necesario agregar más de un `WHERE` en vez de ello intenta con `AND`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No puede haber más de un `WHERE` en una misma consulta**, por ello existen las condiciones `AND` y `OR`, para así poder poner más de una condición al momento de discriminar datos en una sentencia.

Por lo mismo podrías usar un `AND` en tu consulta quitando el segundo `WHERE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT $pregModalidad.numeroPregunta,
--tus demás datos
FROM $pregModalidad 
INNER JOIN respuestasTestUsuario 
ON $pregModalidad.numeroPregunta=respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta 
from respuestasTestUsuario 
WHERE respuestasTestUsuario.respuestasCorrectas=3 AND respuestasTestUsuario.idUsuario=$idUsuario) 
--aqui se cambia el WHERE por un AND
AND $pregModalidad.numeroPregunta=$contaPregunta
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de sintaxis. Es decir tienes un WHERE de más. En lugar de ello está debe ser reemplazada por AND.

Tu código quedaría algo como esto.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN, B.COLUMN 
FROM TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.COLUMN = B.COLUMN 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT COL FROM TABLE3 WHERE ID = A.COLUMN) 
AND B.COLUM = 'FOOBAR'
```